# window.onload in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there any equivalent of window.onload event in Angular?

I want to fade out and remove my preloader but only after all resources like images are loaded. Since $viewConteneLoaded indicates only html insertion into view (i am using ngRotue) listening to it is not sufficient.

I would like to capture window.onload event, but don't know how to do it properly and what is the best-practice for doing it in Angular, so that digest would fire.

Comment: $window.onload = function() {}; try this.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try to use `$window.onload` event.

Example:

```
angular.element($window).bind('load', function() {
    //put your code
});
```

For Angular 12

```
angular.element(window).bind('load', function() {
    //put your code
});
```

Comment: Using $ is not Angularish.

Answer (score 2):

Write the following in the component file:

```
import { HostListener } from '@angular/core';

...

@HostListener('window:load')
onLoad() {
  console.log('is window:load');
}

...
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
   // your code ...
}
```

It runs after the view is fully loaded.
https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit#ngAfterViewInit

Comment: It runs after the components view is fully loaded but window onload loads after all views are fully loaded.

Answer (score -2):

Use angular's init() function to hide your preloader and run it at bottom of your page/controller so that all the content is finished loading before it reaches init function.

Answer (score -3):

You can use `angular.element(document).ready();` as below

```
 angular.element(document).ready(function () {
       //do something
    });
```

Comment: Alas, `ready` method is not for `onload` event. It's for `DOMContentLoaded`.