# Angular: How to listen on window.onload event?

Tags: javascript, angular

In Angular (not AngularJS), how to listen on window.onload event?
(This is not a duplicate of [window.onload in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42502046/window-onload-in-angular), since that question is about AngularJS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Official documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload):

> The load event fires when a given resource has loaded.

In this case the resource is the JavaScript file itself. So the `onload` event is fired long before your angular components are initialised.

You should be instead using [OnInit](https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit) or [AfterViewInit](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit) angular lifecycle events based on what you are trying to do.